# Data drill-down library/canvas/tool

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

I am looking for some visualisation canvas that would allow easy visualisation of many nodes and edges as well as drill-down and exploration. Closest to what I want was [Gephi](http://gephi.org/).

Comment: What language would you like to use?  Also, web app or desktop app?

Comment: Doesn't matter at this point. Anything goes

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html), which is very similar to Gephi.  One thing that I prefer in yEd is the multi-pane layout, so you can view the zoomed out graph for overall orienation, the large view at the current zoom level, and a third perspective - a block and arrow diagram of the current node and it's adjacencies.

Comment: Very nice! I will check it out!